# Change error page for 502 Bad Gateway error Nginx not working

Tags: nginx, 502

I have researched online for a means to change the error page when running into a 502 Bad Gateway error. I have tried all the methods given to no avail. I looked in the nginx.conf file and saw that it points to /usr/share/nginx/html/50x.html when dealing with 500 errors. However this page is never shown. Instead it shows

502 Bad Gateway

---

nginx/1.16.1

What am I missing?

I followed this guide https://blog.adriaan.io/one-nginx-error-page-to-rule-them-all.html

And others, but I am beginning to think that there is another issue altogether that is bypassing my code.

Comment: `error_page` works fine with 502 status messages.

Comment: You should post the non-working configuration here. Everything else is idle speculation and does not help you or other readers. As Richard already mentioned, the feature works fine for millions of installations. So post your code and experts here can work it out.

Answer (score 0):

Sample example is below, kindly change paths and names accordingly.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /custom_50x.html;
    location = /custom_50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            internal;
    }}
```